# VS2010 vs. VS2008 Usage?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, statistics

I'm curious if anyone has some statistics on the usage of VS2008 vs. VS2010?
I'm debating if I should convert my project over to VS2010 from VS2008, just support one version, or try to maintain two solutions.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: SP1 shipped yesterday, lots of fixes.  There's no longer a reason left to do delay doing something you are going to do anyway.  Maintaining two solutions is just a waste of your time.

Answer (score 2):

It basically depends on if you want any of the new features of VS 2010 or they can help you develop a better product. Check out [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386063.aspx) to see what is new in it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C++ i would say, stay on 2008.